# Removed MAMP(PHP 5.5) from Mac and Installed XAMPP(PHP 5.3), but PHP version is still 5.5

Tags: php, xampp, mamp

I removed MAMP(PHP 5.5) from Mac and Installed XAMPP(PHP 5.3), if i open http://localhost/xampp/index.php, it shows its PHP Version 5.3.1

But on command line:
xampp $ php -v;
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25)

It's still 5.5! And all my PHP scripts are still using PHP 5.5! Why is this and how to completely remove PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with your classpath, it's using what is in `/usr/bin/php` rather than `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`.  Try using the full path of the XAMPP one to run your scripts, or alter your path to prefer the xampp one